# When we say "I use .Net version 4.5.1.x", what 4,5,1,x represent in the version?

Tags: version

When we say "I use .Net version 4.5.1.x", what 4,5,1,x represent in the version?

In an interview I have been asked with this question, and I wanted to know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When versions are identified numerically, the numbers are assigned in increasing order. They usually take the form x.y.z, where "x" represents the major version, "y" represents the minor version, and "z" represents the number of the revision. For instance, version 1.3.22 would be major version 1, minor version 3, revision 22.

A major version number is incremented when there is a significant code change that might be incompatible with previous versions, such as a fundamental change of framework.
A minor version number is incremented when significant bug fixes are implemented, or a new feature is added.
A revision number is incremented when minor bug fixes are implemented.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).